# Filter Table by Values from two other tables in Power BI Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my current report in PowerBI I need data from a table "Booking Data" with bookings of users that were not planned. These are to be matched with data from table "Project Members" and entered in a row from table "Projects" as a total Count at the right ID.

Currently I get the number of users who have booked to the respective ID. Now I need to match these names with the "Project Members" fields and if there are not in the "Project Members" table then they need to count.

I got the Tables "Project Members", "Projects" and "Booking Data".

[image]

My current outcome:

```
not Planned User = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Booking Data'[User]),
    FILTER(
        'Booking Data', 
        Projects[ID] = 'Booking Data'[ID]
    ) 
)
```

I am now missing the " matching " with the Project Members table, but so far everything has run on error for me.

Comment: It sounds like you want to group 'Booking Data' by ID (which relates to Projects[ID]) and count the number of records in each group where User has no matching value in 'Project member.'  Is that aright?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would get that "anti-join" counting.  Filter 'BookingData' down to the records that have no match between BookingData[User] and ProjectMember[Project Member].  Then distinct count the user.

When you set this measure alongside a Project column in a visual, you will get the grouping effect that you're after.

```
NotPannedUser =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( BookingData[User] ),
    FILTER (
        BookingData,
        NOT BookingData[User] IN VALUES ( ProjectMember[Project Member] )
    )
)
```